# FileNotFoundError on fresh install ubuntu 22 when running Pyest

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I got a weird error when running pytest in a newly installed ubuntu 22. Google chrome was installed and running fine. However, when I run some tests in my Django project, pytest will yell that a file has not found error.

I'm using `pytest-django==4.5.2` and `pytest==7.2.0`

```
     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock'
```

Here is the test that currently causing pytest to fail

```
 import pytest
 from django.urls import reverse


 @pytest.mark.django_db
 def test_home_view(client):
 """ ensure our default home view is accessable and working"""
    url = reverse('packages')
    response = client.get(url)
    print(f" response {response}")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

In another test file, pytest just running it without errors

```
  def test_DEBUG_env_var_exists():
     if int(DEBUG) > 0:  # debug is set to true in localhost
        pytest.skip("database misconfigured, test skip")
     assert os.environ.get('DEBUG') is not None
```

Any idea why I got `FileNotFound` error and how to fix it?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause of the error. It's really hard and painful to debug when the error message will not point to the real culprit. After re-installing ubuntu and the error still showing, I tried first to remove the env variables one by one until I decided to uncomment  elements one by one in variable lists inside settings until commenting the

```
 "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
```

Inside settings.py

Pytest is yelling with the error without pointing out what might cause it. And running locally or in production just works fine